# PayPal Sandbox: "Your details can not be confirmed"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Paypal Sandbox shows me "Ihre Angaben können nicht bestätigt werden. Versuchen Sie es bitte erneut." (Your details can not be confirmed. Please try again.) after Login with a Sandbox-Buyer Account. Any Ideas what i can do?

Comment: Did you use the correct username and password? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/

Comment: Yes, i did. The login with buyer works. The message appears after successful login.